# Tensorflow load saved model, Predict and Evaluate. Too low accuracy on test?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tpu

I have trained my model on TPU and result seems good for testing. Dataset has 5 classes and result shows that:

`accuracy: 0.9867 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9867 - loss: 0.0412 - val_accuracy: 0.9859 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9859 - val_loss: 0.0564 - lr: 1.8013e-07`

[My Sparse Categorical Accuracy Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXm3E.png)

I saved model as .h5 file as described [Tensorflow Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#keras_h5_format)

I loaded **TPU_model.h5** using
`reconstructed_model = keras.models.load_model("TPU_model.h5")`.  When I use
`reconstructed_model.predict_classes(tensored_image)`, result is incorrect.  Tried `reconstructed_model.evaluate`, same result. I think about **overfitting**, tested prediction with image that used on training, result is incorrect.
My latest load and predict code.

```
reconstructed_model= load_model('TPU_Model_Final.h5')
reconstructed_model= tf.keras.Sequential([reconstructed_model,tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])
reconstructed_model.compile(loss=loss,
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy','sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

classes = reconstructed_model.predict_classes(images, batch_size=10)
```

I follwed this tutorial([Tensorflor - Basic classification: Classify images of clothing](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification#make_predictions))

Comment: I created a notebook with the same dataset that might help-->https://www.kaggle.com/brendanartley/fashion-mnist-keras-cnn. If you could provide more information about the training/prediction/model that would help us help you!

Comment: My create model code gist: [gist.github.com/Nobatgeldi/42093bf7f1e4fc837e7b38ce43df0f63](https://gist.github.com/Nobatgeldi/42093bf7f1e4fc837e7b38ce43df0f63). I had trained my model on TPU, do I need to do something for saved model if I want use it on CPU or GPU?

Comment: You don't need to compile again your saved model. Just load the model and then predict.

Comment: Still same result, model can not correctly predict trained images. How it can be? Result:  `accuracy: 0.9867 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9867 - loss: 0.0412 - val_accuracy: 0.9859 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9859 - val_loss: 0.0564 - lr: 1.8013e-07`

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating the same model with [sample dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images)
with the same good accuracy while model training and evaluation and found that it's predicting the images correctly.

```
Epoch 10/10
92/92 [==============================] - 39s 423ms/step - loss: 0.0750 - accuracy: 0.9734 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9734 - val_loss: 0.9160 - val_accuracy: 0.8692 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8692
```

Verified the same accuracy after loading back the model:

```
reconstructed_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("TPU_Model_Final.h5")

reconstructed_model.evaluate(val_ds)
```

Output:

```
23/23 [==============================] - 5s 106ms/step - loss: 0.9160 - accuracy: 0.8692 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8692
[0.9159510135650635, 0.8692098259925842, 0.8692098259925842]
```

The prediction part:
 (`predict_classes()` is deprecated, hence using `predict()` and `argmax()` to show the prediction)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")
```

Output:

[image]

Predicting the second image on the above 9 images:

```
classes = reconstructed_model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
pred = np.argmax(classes[1])
class_names[pred]
```

Output:

```
sunflowers
```

Verify with the actual label:

```
actual_labels=labels[1]
class_names[actual_labels]
```

Output:

```
sunflowers
```